# Send data inside HTML output tags to Google Sheet

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, output

I've created an HTML form that calculates and shows the outputs of calculations based on inputs in the form. (The calculated outputs are driving time and distance based on start and end address inputs in the form.)

How can I send HTML outputs to a Google Sheet? Or is there another way to send the calculations (e.g. inside span tags)?

I can send the input fields okay.

Here's the code for sending the HTML form data to the Google Sheet.

I tried adding ("output") to the $form.find but it didn't work.

```
var request;
```

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){

```
// Abort any pending request
if (request) {
    request.abort();
}
// setup some local variables
var $form = $(this);

// Let's select and cache all the fields
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

// Serialize the data in the form
var serializedData = $form.serialize();

// Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
// Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
// Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);

// Fire off the request to /form.php
request = $.ajax({
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/MYAPIKEY/exec",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});

// Callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Log a message to the console
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    console.log(response);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
});

// Callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// Callback handler that will be called regardless
// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    // Reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});

// Prevent default posting of form
event.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: For me its not clear what you want to achieve. GoogleSheet and mySQL are two completely different things

Comment: I want to send HTML form data, including some output fields, to Google Sheets. I can send the input fields but not the output ones.

Comment: What are "output" fields?

Comment: I mean data inside HTML output tags. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

Comment: this are simple HTML elements. E.g. you can give them an id <output id="result"> and get the content by $('#result').html()

Comment: How do I add that to the script above, in terms of syntax? I tried var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea, #price");   , for example (one of the fields is <output id="price" name="price>   but it didn't work. (Thanks a lot for your help.)

Comment: The Id must be unique. So you can access it like I wrote just by the id. Let price = parseint($('#price').html())

Comment: Thanks. But I'm afraid I don't know where to add this code "$('#result').html()" in the script. I'm guessing it needs to be added to var $inputs somehow, but I don't know how, I'm afraid.

Comment: My level of understanding is basic. I'm trying to learn more. We all start somewhere. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Managed to find a solution using formData.append('name', var). Issue resolved.